# min3D src code implimentation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, 3d, min3d

I am currently exploring possibilities of what is possible in java as I am learning java. I like the idea of add 3D models into my apps. I came across min3D which looks and sounds very easy to use. I am following this tutorial [Link](http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-load-a-3d-obj-model-with-min3d-for-android/) which seems simple enough. My question is, why can't I just simple import an api for min3D?

I have been googling for a while now and there isn't really a tutorial of how to include to min3D src into a project. I have found that when importing the project that containing all the code, there is errors on every line of each document.
[src code](https://github.com/DavidYKay/min3d)

Is there something else that can be used to import 3D models into my project. (like papervision in flash)

If it helps I am using cinema 4D to create models/meshes and eclipse for the android/java

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED IT***
All I had to do was copy and paste the folder min3D from inside the src within the downloaded examples folder directly into the src folder of my app. No errors all packages and examples work fine.
This linked helped, [min3d/issues](https://code.google.com/p/min3d/issues/detail?id=49)